# Count with Condition in laravel Eloquent

Tags: database, eloquent, laravel-5.1, aggregate

I want to count users who have stripe_plan = platinum_monthly

```
$platinum=User::count('stripe_plan','platinum_monthly');
```

But its returning all users who have selected any available plan 
how to solve this issue need help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try adding the condition in a where clause

```
$platinum=User::where('stripe_plan','platinum_monthly')->count();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$platinum = User::where('stripe_plan', 'platinum_monthly')->count();
```

You have to select the users you want to count, not "count the users you want to count".

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done like

```
$platinum=User::where('stripe_plan', 'platinum_monthly')->count();
```